# How to show reign of area using SurfaceView and SurfaceHolder?

Tags: android-camera, surfaceview

I would like to know if there is a way to show only a reign of area of the camera that shown on a SurfaceView.

I've got an image like that (microscopic image)[image: Full Image]

and I want to show image like that(Cropped and **Stretched**): 
[image: Cropped and Stretched image]

This is a part of my code(it is a basic code that show the camera on SurfaceView using SurfaceHolder):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_testing);

overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

cameraView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.CameraView);

    holder = cameraView.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

    @Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();

        parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);

        //parameters.setZoom(10);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();

        final Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                StartTest(0);
                myTimer.cancel();
                myTimer.purge();
            }
        },10000, 10); 


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
    private void initRecorder() {
    camera.unlock();

    recorder.setCamera(camera);
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile
            .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
    recorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
    recorder.setMaxFileSize(300000000); // Approximately 5 megabytes

    recorder.setOutputFile(VIDEO_PATH);

}
private void prepareRecorder() {

    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this for the preview or the captured image (or both)?  If you send the preview to a `SurfaceTexture` you can render it with GLES and do any number of transformations, but that can be a bit of work.  Also, one of us is confused about what "reign" means.

Comment: I'm using MediaExtractor and MediaCodec to do some manipulations on the recorded video. and there I'm using SurfaceTexture. How hard is it to work on the GLES?

Comment: Take a look at "Show + capture camera" in https://github.com/google/grafika .  There's a bit of a bump getting used to EGL and surface manipulation.

Comment: I'm followed by [ExtractMpegFramesTest.java Tutorial](http://www.bigflake.com/mediacodec/)
Can I show the frame from the MediaCodec to the surface?

Comment: The ExtractMpegFramesTest has most of what you want.  Instead of rendering it offscreen to a pbuffer, you want to render it to a window surface (created from SurfaceView -> SurfaceHolder -> Surface).  It may be easier to follow in Grafika -- look at WindowSurface vs. OffscreenSurface in https://github.com/google/grafika/tree/master/src/com/android/grafika/gles .  You can pick which part of the captured image to display by setting the texture coordinates to something other than (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0) (which covers the entire image).

Comment: The question is if it is possible to also show the image on surface view and work in it as a puffer,  because that at the same time I need to do some manipulation on the input frame and also show the current video.

Comment: It the manipulation you want to do can be done with GL (crop, scale, rotate, basic color tweaks like in the "Show + capture camera" activity in Grafika), then you can do them as part of the rendering pipeline.  If you need something more complicated, you may need to manipulate the camera frames directly.  You can render the data to the SurfaceView by drawing on it from software (via Canvas) or uploading your modified image as a GL texture (glTexImage2D) and rendering from that  Can you update your question with a couple of paragraphs explaining what specifically you want to do?